# Symfony 1.4 completely remove the use of configuration cache

Tags: caching, configuration, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have to host my Symfony 1.4 project in an environment where there is no write permission to any directory.
I want to completely disable the use of cache in Symfony as my application won't run if its enabled.

I searched the internet and moved my cache dir to system TEMP but that won't solve my problem as i am unable to clear it when i make any configuration changes, which makes my application dead.

It won't have much traffic, maybe only 1 user always, so performance is not an issue.

Kindly guide me how can i run my symfony project without any kind of cache.
I can follow the instructions and capable of doing core level changes.

-Regards

Comment: Let me understand, you can deploy your project, by cpanel or ftp, but you can't change any directory permissions ?

Comment: not like that, i am working for a department which has its own data center, but due to some security policies, they don't provide write permission to any directory.

My problem is that Symfony needs a directory where it puts .php files generated by parsing .yml files, and i can't provide that directory. I can let my application parse .yml every time the page loads, but needs to get rid of the write permission requirement.

Comment: I found this interesting link http://www.zalas.eu/symfony-meets-apc-alternative-php-cache but I think this can't solve the problem with the configuration cache... I hope this can point you in a right direction but really I think it's a target very difficult to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line in your filters.yml file for you application that represents cache.

```
rendering: ~
security:  ~

# insert your own filters here
profile:
  class: profileFilter

#  TAKE THIS LINE OUT
cache:     ~
execution: ~
```

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, Symfony still wants a cache directory to work.
I want to run Symfony without write permission to any directory